# How to show all entry y value in the same x line in Swift?

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I'm making a line chart by using iOS-charts framework. I have 3 line or set. Sometimes it will overlay each other so I made a balloon marker. It will show the value when hover the point but it only show 1 y value. How to show all the y value in the same x line?

similar question but no solve yet : https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/2173

This code is on BalloonMarker.swift, it is for edit the marker value.

```
public override func refreshContent(entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
    setLabel(String(entry.y))
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My solution

```
public override func refreshContent(entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
    let set = chartView?.data?.dataSets[0]
    let set1 = chartView?.data?.dataSets[1]
    let setEntry = set?.entryForIndex(Int(entry.x))
    let setEntry2 = set1?.entryForIndex(Int(entry.x))
    let month = Int(entry.x + 1.0)

    setLabel(String("\(month)月\n 收入：\(setEntry?.y ?? 0.0)\n 支出：\(setEntry2?.y ?? 0.0)"))
}
```